# swift error occurs when only the optional parameters are added to the declared type of function

Tags: ios, swift

Why can't I do this:

```
let simpleClosure: (String) -> Void = { _ in 

}

var testClosure: (String?) -> Void
testClosure = simpleClosure
```

On the other hand, this code does not cause errors:

```
let simpleClosure: (String?) -> Void = { _ in 

}

var testClosure: (String) -> Void
testClosure = simpleClosure
```

Is there a difference between the two codes? I'd appreciate it if you let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler considers `String` as a subtype of `String?`. Any `String` can be assigned to a variable of `String?`, but not the other way round. The compiler automatically wraps your non-optional string to an optional.

Closures are [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) on their parameters. This means that you can assign a `(T) -> Void` to a variable typed `(U) -> Void` if `U` is a subtype of `T`. In your working code, `U` is `String` and `T` is `String?`.

If you are not convinced that this contravariance is safe, think about what the variable `testClosure` is said to contain. It contains a closure that can accept any `String` and returns `Void`. Is `simpleClosure` such a closure? Well, can `simpleClosure` accept any `String`? Yes it certainly can. Not only can it accept any string, it can also accept `nil` (that's what `String?` means), but `testClosure` doesn't care.

On the other hand, in your non-working code, `testClosure` is said to contain a closure that can accept any string *and* `nil`. `simpleClosure` isn't such a closure, because it can't accept `nil`.

Comment: Thank you Sweeper. I'm studying Swift. I'm going to have to study contravariant . It was easy to understand because you explained it well